# GFci replacement wiring question

Tags: wiring, gfci

I am replacing my GFi and I see that only the white wire on the line from the junction box is wired into the line side.  The black wire on the line side is there but not screwed on to a terminal. Is this possible for it to operate this way? Or now I’m thinking that perhaps this is my original problem. The circuit has worked fine for years but just started to throw the breaker which lead to this repair. Should I just go with the instructions an wire it in. ?

Comment: A loose black wire will give quite a few problems, from outlet or switch or light just not working to the house burning down.  Code now to use a torque wrench/screwdriver when attaching wires/stuff to devices.

Comment: Can you post some pictures, please? I'm having trouble visualizing "The black wire on the line side is there but not screwed on to a terminal."

Comment: Well, GFCIs have an alternate connection method called "screw-and-clamp" where the wire goes in the back but is clamped down by tightening the screw. Don't back the screw all the way out, it will come about 5mm out and then hit a stop, don't force it past the stop.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Probably better to say "some higher-quality outlets" rather than "GFCIs" for the back-wiring. I've seen GFCIs without it, and better non-GFCI outlets with it.